# php unset after foreach

Tags: php, foreach, unset

I have a kind of store where members of a ski club can rent equipment. The first step is a loop where the member can make repetitive choices, for example for him and his family. Each line of material has its own total with a grand total at the bottom. A problem occurs once the last renting has been done and the member want to finalize his payment. The line of the last rented equipment is doubled and as a result the grand total is false. An idea how to solve this. I think it has something to do with my UNSET instruction. Thanks for helping. Here is the code of my foreach loops:

```
foreach ($price as $key => $value) {
   $number[$key] = str_pad($number[$key], 2);
   $type[$key] = str_pad($type[$key], 21);
   $lenght[$key] = str_pad($lenght[$key], 15);
   $boots[$key] = str_pad($boots[$key], 22);
   $size[$key] = str_pad($size[$key], 15);
   $priceskipers[$key] = ($priceski[$key]) * ($person[$key]);
   $pricebootspers[$key] = ($priceboots[$key]) * ($person[$key]);
   $total[$key] = array_sum(array($priceskipers[$key], $pricebootspers[$key]));
   $supertotal = 0;  
   $id++;
   echo "<pre>Data : " .$date[$key] . " | " . $number[$key] . " / " . $person[$key] . "| " . $type[$key] . " | " . $lenght[$key] . " | " . $boots[$key] . " | " . $size[$key] . "<br> " . $priceskipers[$key] . " + " . $pricebootspers[$key] . "  =  " . $total[$key] . " for this reservation (id" . $id . ").<hr></pre>";    
      unset($value);
      foreach ($total as $key2 => $value2) {
   $supertotal += $total[$key2];  
   $discount = (($supertotal) * 0.2);
   $grandtotal = (($supertotal) - ($discount));
  }
  }
   echo "<pre><b>Total " . $supertotal . " - 20% (discount for online renting) " . $discount . " = " . $grandtotal . ", your net amount.</b></pre>";
```

Comment: You should fix the cause, not the effect. Find out what cause the duplication and fix it.

Comment: What's the purpose of your `unset($value)`? I don't even see you using that variable in anyway. The `$value` variable is just a copy of the actual value in the `$price` array, it doesn't affect the `$price` array at all. Conclusion, the `unset($value)` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: That's my basic question? I don't know if the unset is mandatory. With or without the instruction, the result is the same: a double calculation of the last line.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, better you should provide fully each of your real input variables so that community can simulate easier.

Even the code above was not a proper way but it still works. No point for the `unset()` call to go here.

Next, a bit refactor, move the last `foreach` block out of the main loop: #1

```
foreach ($price as $key => $value) {
    //old logic
}

foreach ($total as $key2 => $value2) {
    $supertotal += $total[$key2];
    $discount = (($supertotal) * 0.2);
    $grandtotal = (($supertotal) - ($discount));
}
```

Next, you can even remove the whole calculation in `foreach` loop of #1 by:

```
$superTotal = array_sum($total);
$discount = $superTotal * 0.2;
$grandTotal = $superTotal - $discount;
```

Last, your comment is about when after all user click on pay button then things get broken, it means the calculation then totally depend on how the event after `click on pay button`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is not working. The result is the same a double count at the end

Comment: Thought you were asking how to unset. So I gave my answer. Back to your logic breaking problem. What line in your codes mean `The line of the last rented equipment is doubled` ?

Comment: It's explained above. For example: 1/ you rent a ski for 20, the system creates a line with a total of 20 and a grandtotal 20. 2/ you rent a second ski for 30, the system creates a second line with a total of 30 and a grandtotal of 50. 3/ Now you want to confirm and pay. If you click "Pay", a third line with 30 is created and the grand total is then equal to 80. That's wrong, I don't know why a third line is created.